# How to encrypt URL parameter - React.js - Js - Node.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, encryption, password-protection, password-encryption

I am building an app that sends password/email in URL request:
For Example http://localhost:3000/getUserId/email?email=myEmail@gmail.com or the same with the password

I don't want this sensitive information to be visible on the network and would like to protect it from potential hacking or sniffing furthermore.

The front is using React.js and back Node.js - How can I encrypt that sensitive information?
I guess using btoa and atob is not enough since anyone could use them for decryption right?

Comment: Never put credentials into the URL. Use TLS (i.e. HTTPS) to encrypt the requests (and responses, of course).

Answer (score 2):

You have at least two issues.

If you send confidential information like e-mail addresses and passwords over a network, you have to not only encrypt it but also make sure that potential network-based attackers don't have the ability to alter the traffic. This is done by employing HTTP over TLS or better known under HTTPS.

The other thing is that passwords should never be set in the URL. Most web servers provide logging capabilities and happily log the password in that case. But since passwords should be [hashed repeatedly](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/211/45523) that would defeat that purpose.